# Make an array of the multiple select fields

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a project in which I have to make a user role system .its almost done but at the end where I have to add the route and user permission in the database I got an array like

```
[route] => Array
    (
        [0] => api/user
        [1] => members
    )

[assess] => Array
    (
        [0] => read
        [1] => write
        [2] => read
        [3] => delete
    )
```

But what I need is to get array like

```
[0](
    [route] => Array
        (
            [0] => api/user
        )
    [assess] => Array
        (
            [0] => read
            [1] => write
        )
)
[1](
    [route] => Array
        (
            [0] => members
        )
    [assess] => Array
        (
            [0] => read
        )
);
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tbody class="tbody">
    <tr class="gradeX">
      <td>
      <select name="route[]">
        <?php $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
          foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
              echo '<option value="'.$value->getPath().'">'.$value->getPath().'</option>';
          } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="read" name="check[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="write" name="check[]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="delete" name="check[]"></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:;" style="padding: 3px 9px;" class="remove">Delete</a></td>
        <div class="add-row" style="float: right;border: 1px dashed grey;border-radius:5px;border-bottom: 0px;">
            <a href="javascript:;" style="padding: 3px 9px;"><span class="add">Add New</span></a>
        </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: How do you split? Based on what logic?

Comment: Based on your two array it's not possible. You have tell us the logic what is going to implement to get your desired output

Comment: How are we supposed to determine the route and their associated assesses?

Comment: how you want to merge your array ?

Comment: i just need this for further use @Praveen Kumar

Comment: how are you getting the row from the database, you most likely need a while statement to loop through

Comment: can you please post the html code here ?

Comment: please look at the edit Question @rahul Sir

Comment: Are you expecting the result while you press "Add New" button?

Answer (score 0):

As only checked checkboxes are submitted on form submit, and to link your checkboxes to your selects, add a `key` value to all name array attributes -

```
<tbody class="tbody">
    <tr class="gradeX">
      <td>
      <select name="route[0]">
        <?php $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
          foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
              echo '<option value="'.$value->getPath().'">'.$value->getPath().'</option>';
          } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="read" name="check[0][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="write" name="check[0][]"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="delete" name="check[0][]"></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:;" style="padding: 3px 9px;" class="remove">Delete</a></td>
        <div class="add-row" style="float: right;border: 1px dashed grey;border-radius:5px;border-bottom: 0px;">
            <a href="javascript:;" style="padding: 3px 9px;"><span class="add">Add New</span></a>
        </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

*You will need to increment the key in your javascript code for 'Add New' for this to work*

Then in php, you can loop over your values, using the `key` to link, ie.

```
$array = [];
foreach($_POST['route'] as $key => $value){
    $array[] = array("route" => array($_POST['route'][$key]), // this is the route value, ie. api/user or members
                     "assess" => array($_POST['check'][$key]) //this is the check array, ie. read, write or read
               );
}
```

Comment: sir i have a working jQuery script for append a new row

Comment: I figured that, so you just need to modify that jQuery script to increase the `key` when you append a new row.